# SQL relative versus absolute date impact query time

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

I run the following query and it takes 50 seconds.

```
select created_at, currency, balance 
from YYY
where id in (ZZZ) and currency = 'XXX'
and created_at >= '2020-08-28'
order by created_at desc
limit 1;
```

explain:

```
Limit  (cost=100.12..1439.97 rows=1 width=72)  
->  Foreign Scan on yyy  (cost=100.12..21537.65 rows=16 width=72)
        Filter: (("substring"((object_key)::text, '\w+:(\d+):.*'::text))::integer = 723120)
```

Then I run the following query and it "infinite" time. Too long to wait until the end.

```
select created_at, currency, balance 
from YYY
where id in (ZZZ) and currency = 'XXX'
and created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL '1 DAY'
order by created_at desc
limit 1;
```

explain:

```
Limit  (cost=53293831.90..53293831.91 rows=1 width=72)
  ->  Result  (cost=53293831.90..53293987.46 rows=17284 width=72)
        ->  Sort  (cost=53293831.90..53293840.54 rows=17284 width=556)
              Sort Key: yyy.created_at DESC
              ->  Foreign Scan on yyy  (cost=100.00..53293814.62 rows=17284 width=556)
                    Filter: ((created_at >= (now() - '1 day'::interval)) AND (("substring"((object_key)::text, '\w+:(\d+):.*'::text))::integer = 723120))
```

What could make this huge difference between those query. I know that index are used to improve performance. What can we infer from here?
Any contribution would be appreciated.

Comment: The time periods are not the same.  One possibility is that you have a lot of data just before 2020-08-28.

Comment: Is the table partitioned? Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The point was not there sorry. I tried the method with 1 day back. Same outcome, the query last and i don't see the end...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am not sure what you called partitioned. I will check about it first. Thanks

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) of both queries (a simple `explain` will do) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: 1) Could you provide us with the [`explain`s](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-explain/) for those queries? 2) [Check for locks](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring). 3) Try `'2020-08-29' - INTERVAL '1 DAY'` which should be equivalent to `'2020-08-28'` just to eliminate a change in the result size as a possibility. 4) Try `select count(created_at)` to also eliminate fetch time as a possibility.

Comment: Do you have an index on `created_at`? What is the data type for `created_at`? I suspect  it has to do with use of `NOW()` which returns timestamptz. That would not play well with something expecting immutable values. Have you tried `LOCALTIMESTAMP` instead?

Comment: @Schwern I have added the explain. Please help to understand

Comment: So `yyy` is a foreign table. That explains a lot. The Postgres FDW simply can't push down such a condition to the remote server, while the constant _can_ be pushed down to the foreign server. Does using `current_date - 1` work?  The execution plan of the first query shows a completely different WHERE clause though (nothing with `created_at`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the `current_date - 1` does not work. I don't know why the execution plan  is so different. The `where` clause with created_at is there though

Answer (score 1):

With a literal, the optimizer has an easy game to plan an efficient data access using the right index.

With an expression like `NOW - INTERVAL '4 DAY'`, you run at least into two challenges:

- It is a stable, not an immutable, expression. Let alone a literal.
- The expression is a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, not a `DATE`, and you need an implicit type cast.

You just make the life of the optimizer difficult ...

I just created a single-column table `yyy` with 12 years' worth of distinct dates in my PostgreSQL database. No indexes. Already here, you see a difference in the cost of the explain plan.

```
$ psql -c "explain select * from yyy where created_at >= '2020-08-28'"
                      QUERY PLAN                      
------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on yyy  (cost=0.00..74.79 rows=126 width=4)
   Filter: (created_at >= '2020-08-28'::date)
```

And:

```
$ psql -c "explain select * from yyy where created_at >= now() - interval '4 day'"
                       QUERY PLAN                       
--------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on yyy  (cost=0.00..96.70 rows=126 width=4)
   Filter: (created_at >= (now() - '4 days'::interval))
(2 rows)
```

It will be a much worse difference with the existence of an index ....